# Xamarin iOS terminates on simulator after running test recorder

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I originally asked this here

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79195/xamin-app-terminated-in-simulator-after-using-test-recorder-please-help#latest

Just like it says. After I've used test recorder, the simulator will always terminate the app with a log message of "exited due to invalid code signature". I have a feeling it is because of this:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/testrecorder/

> When recording tests for an iOS application, the Test Recorder will
>   automatically inject a special library called the Test Recorder Plugin
>   into the app bundle (Android apps do not need this library). The Test
>   Recorder Plugin is extra code that allows the Test Recorder to observe
>   the application that is being tested and generated the C# code for the
>   various events. The presence of this library is grounds for the Apple
>   App Store to reject the app bundle; do not submit any IPAs that were
>   used by the Test Recorder to the App Store for distribution.

How do I undo this? I've already uninstalled the app from the simulator, cleaned and rebuilt the project.

Comment: Have you also deleted the mtbs folder on your mac? Delete `/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs` and delete bin and obj and try to rebuild

Comment: All this note is saying is to not use any of the generated `.ipa` files in publishing. You can easily generate another `.ipa` without using the Test Recorder which will be fine to submit for publishing.

Comment: Thanks, I will delete those folders and try again. I did go in to the caches/xamarin folder and delete some things.  Not sure if I deleted the mtbs folder.  It was strange I kept cleaning and rebuilding but the simulator kept producing the same app version and terminating.  I was afraid that using the test recorder would cause to be unable to submit to the store.   So it sounds like the rebuild and generate a new ipa will not have the injected library in it?  Maybe the difference is I'm debugging on similator with project config 'debug' , but building ipa with project config 'ad hoc, device'

Comment: I believe it should work even in `Debug` it's simply when you invoke the build via hitting `Record` on Test Recorder is when the items are injected in the respective `ipa`. Closing out of the Test Recorder, clearing your build caches and regenerating should resolve this issue.

Comment: Ok deleting the cache, obj, bin did NOT work.  Same result

Comment: For me switching between debug & release finally worked.

I've also cleaned the project, removed obj & bin folders, cleared keychain on simulator, reset content and settings on simulator, removed simulator devices and reinstall, removed provisioning profiles in xcode and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings? It's possible the resigned app is getting cached by the simulator (even after uninstalling) and not installing the rebuilt app from Xamarin Studio. Test Recorder always resigns the .app/.ipa as a separate file with the prepended 'xtr'-filename.